# How can I securely erase a file?

Tags: ruby, secure-coding

Is there a Gem or means of securely erasing a file in Ruby? I'd like to avoid external programs that may not be present on the system.

By "secure erase" I'm referring to overwriting the file contents.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on *nix, a pretty good way would be to just call shred using exec/open3/open4:

```
`shred -fxuz #{filename}`
```

http://www.gnu.org/s/coreutils/manual/html_node/shred-invocation.html

Check this similar post:

[Writing a file shredder in python or ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758868/writing-a-file-shredder-in-python-or-ruby)

Comment: _"I'd like to avoid external programs that may not be present on the system."_ I assume that means one cannot assume what OS is used, but desired to run wherever Ruby runs.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this will get you started:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

abort "Missing filename" if (ARGV.empty?)

ARGV.each do |filename|
  filesize = File.size(filename)
  [0x00, 0xff].each do |byte|
    File.open(filename, 'wb') do |fo|
      filesize.times { fo.print(byte.chr) }
    end
  end
end
```

It should get you close.

For more thoroughness, you could also use `0xaa` and `0x55` for alternating 0 and 1 bits in the byte. `Random.rand(0xff)` will give you a random value from 0 to 255.

Comment: This is not guaranteed to actually affect the physical storage previously used for the file - the old data will likely still be on the drive, with the new data written elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

just

1. open the file
2. write some garbage at least in amount equal to current file size
3. `flush()` and `close()`
4. repeat N times, mixing garbage with zeroes and `0xff`'s on different passes